# how can I get a program to run if the user has inputted at least one character?

Tags: python-3.x

how can I get a get a program to run if the user has inputted at least one character. For example:

```
userinput = input("Enter your age: ")
if (user input) > (at least one character/number):
    print(blank)
```

To clarify, I am wondering how if a user input has more than one character, how to make the if statement run (or any other statement)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `len()` function to check the length of the input. so your code will look like.

```
userinput = input("Enter your age: ")
if len(userinput) >= 1:
    print(userinput)
```

In this case if the input contains any character or space the if statement will work. If your looking for only character or digits then you can use the `re` module to check for the input contents. In this case you write your code as.

```
import re


userinput = input("Enter your age: ")
if re.search(r'[0-9A-Za-z]+', userinput):
    print(userinput)
```

This regular expression will search for any digit or character and if found will set the condition to True.